# Does one say “emes” at night?

Tags: shema

When saying Kriat Shema Al Hamita, if one were saying all three paragraphs, would they said “emes” at the end? It seems to me that the reason we say “emes” is to attach it to the next paragraph, which wouldn’t seem to apply on Kristin Shema Al HaMita.

Comment: Do you mean saying it once as it appears in the passuk, or repeating it as one does with a congregation at Shacharit and Avrit?

Comment: I have received psak that I should say "emes" when I am reciting the full Shema in the morning during Leolam Yehei Adam. It therefore stands to reason that psak holds for Kriyas Shema Al Hamita as well.

Comment: @Yehuda very interesting. Is this instead of saying it as part of the main kriyat shema b'shacharit or in addition to that?

Comment: @JoshK It doesn’t appear at all in the pasuk in Bamidbar

Comment: @JoshK I asked it as a shailah of zman. If I was going to miss the zman and I'm saying Shema in l'olam yehei adam, should I say emes and the answer was yes. Whether that means instead of or in addition to, I'm not sure..... ;)

Answer (score 1):

The Chabad custom is to repeat the words ה' אלקיכם and then also say אמת even during the Bedtime Shema, this is recorded in [Sefer Haminhagim](http://www.sichos-in-english.org/books/sefer-haminhagim/25.htm) and also the [Igros Kodesh](https://www.igrot.com/answer/16/294). It's even printed in the [Chabad siddur](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32581&st=&pgnum=120&hilite=) this way as well.

The reason is to arrive at 248 words altogether, corresponding to the 248 limbs as brought forth in [Chatzkel's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/126845/11486), quoting the Mishnah Berurah.
Some people accomplish this by saying 3 words (א-ל מלך נאמן) before the Shema's 245. This however could be considered an interruption between the blessings before the Shema and the Shema itself therefore Chabad and others do it this way, by repeating the words ה' אלקיכם and saying אמת (see [Kaf Hachayim OC 61:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.61.15.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) and [ibid. 19](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.61.19.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en), also [Beis Yosef OC 61](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Yosef%2C_Orach_Chaim.61.1.1?lang=en)).

Comment: "an interruption between the blessings before the Shema and the Shema itself" But there are no blessings on Shema here?

Comment: @DoubleAA Hashkiveinu

Comment: That's not a blessing here and it's not before shema anyway

Comment: @DoubleAA chabad is careful not to make a hefsek between them and it does precede shema in the chabad siddur

Comment: Chabad is careful not to make a hefsek between a text which is part of a bracha for *after* shema, that happens to be *before* shema and lacking any bracha-formulation (like God's name or even the word ברוך), and shema itself? Why??

Comment: @DoubleAA i honestly would need to look more into it but this is pretty standard in all of chabad, consider how the minhag is to not say veshomru on friday night for the same reason.

Comment: No, that's to avoid a break between geulah and tefilla, not between hashkivenu and shema (!?). That doesn't apply here.

Comment: @DoubleAA why make a change from maariv to here? It would seem strange to arrive at the number of words in maariv one way and then suddenly follow a different nusach at bedtime

Answer (score 0):

The Mishnah Berura 239:1 says that the purpose of saying the entire shema at bedtime is for a shemira in all 248 limbs. This would indicate that one would have to say Emes to reach the number 248:

> וטוב לומר תמיד כל ק"ש שהיא רמ"ח תיבות [בצירוף אל מלך נאמן] לשמור רמ"ח אבריו

Comment: Wouldn't the א-ל מלך נאמן accomplish that? It sounds as if the MB is specifically paskening to use אמ"ן rather than ה' אלוקיכם אמת to reach 248.

Comment: ^ That. Sounds like no Emes?

Comment: @derdeer with Emes you get 245, there MB is saying that you need the other 3 to get to 248. You Emes You’d still only have 247. By davening we repeat 3 words instead but on the first round you need Emes to get 245

Comment: I’m pretty sure Emes gets you too 246. (I think?)

Comment: @michael MB 61:8 is clear that emes would get you to 249. That being said, the reason for connecting ה' אלוקיכם with אמת is because there is a pasuk Yirmiyahu 10:10 with those words and they are nice words to go together. The 248 thing isn't why WE say emes, its why the chazzan repeats 3 words. Unfortunately I cant find the sources for this right now.

Comment: But I do believe it would be strange to say emes when there's no paragraph beginning with that word right afterwards. Although the chazzan does just that, according to MB 61:8, so maybe it's not so strange.

Comment: So I am not sure if that answers the question. Does one say Emes outside of davening?